# SELECT query with IN condition from Node to MariaDB connector always returns single row

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I want to get multiple user records from MariaDB:

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool(...);
const conn = await pool.getConnection();
const query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (?)`;
const rows = await conn.query(query, [requestTargets]);
```

where requestTargets is a string of ids like '123,124,125'

The problem is that this results in array-type 'rows' with single element - the user with id which is the first in requestTargets.

I've tried making the same request from phpmyadmin and it returned valid result of multiple records.

I've tried to pass requestTargets in different format to query (as an array of integers or strings) but this resulted in SQL errors.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending an array from an array as a parameter.

Example:

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool(...);
const conn = await pool.getConnection();
const query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (?)`;
const rows = await conn.query(query, [[requestTargets]]);
```

Comment: The result is the same - only the first user record

Comment: And if I send "SELECT * FROM user" - it returns an array of all users as expected

Comment: And if I hard-code ids to query like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (123,124)` - it returns valid result of two records too.

Answer (score 0):

Binding a list into an `IN()` clause is probably not handled in any Connector.

If `id` is numeric, then you need to end up with `IN (123,124)`; that is *no* quotes.

If it is a string, then you need lots of strings:  `IN ('ab', 'cde')`